# here.com API giving 400 bad request error

Tags: javascript, routes, here-api

i am using the here.com api for calculating the distance between two location of Lawrenceville, GA, United States & Lockbourne Dr  and , see the url below

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=API_KEY&waypoint0=geo!33.95312,-83.98804&waypoint1=geo!39.26732,-84.54907&routeattributes=wp,sm,sh,sc&mode=fastest;truck. but its giving me an error of 400 bad reqest. I getting the below response.

```
{"_type":"ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType","type":"ApplicationError","subtype":"NoRouteFound","details":"Error is NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED","additionalData":[{"key":"error_code","value":"NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED"}],"metaInfo":{"timestamp":"2021-04-06T17:35:53Z","mapVersion":"8.30.119.151","moduleVersion":"7.2.202114-8610","interfaceVersion":"2.6.76","availableMapVersion":["8.30.119.151"]}}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [here documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-type-error-no-route-found.html) this looks like 'no route could be constructed based on the input parameter'.